# Return substring of analyzed, non-stored text field in elasticsearch java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I work on a project that has a string field (the name is urlOrContent) and it can be small (less than 50 character) or very long (more than 50 character), and I just want to return the first 50 characters every time based on a specific query. My database is elasticsearch and my problem is raised in [this link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/return-substring-of-analyzed-non-stored-text-field/83231) and the questioner’s response seems to be correct (urlOrContent field is analyzed and non stored text field). It uses following script:

```
{
   "script_fields": {
      "substring": {
         "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "inline": "params._source.text.substring(0, 100)"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But my main problem is that I can not find the equivalent of elasticsearch java api code. In fact, what should be added to the code below, which only returns the first 50 characters of the urlOrContent field? Note that this field may not even have 50 characters in some cases, and then the entire string should be returned.

```
String queryString =
    EnumLinkFields.CREATE_TIME.getFieldName() + ":(>=" + dateFrom + " AND <=" + dateTo + ")";

QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(queryString);

SearchResponse response = TRANSPORT_CLIENT.prepareSearch(MY_INDEX)
                .setTypes(MY_TYPE)
                .setSearchType(SEARCH_TYPE)
                .setQuery(query)
                .setFetchSource(null, new String[]{EnumLinkFields.USER_ID.getFieldName()})
                .setFrom(offset)
                .setSize(count)
                .addSort(orderByField, sortOrder)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: why can't you use the script in the elasticsearch query?

Comment: excuse me, I'm new to elasticsearch. Would you please explain how to use script in in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best answer.

```
String queryString =
    EnumLinkFields.CREATE_TIME.getFieldName() + ":(>=" + dateFrom + " AND <=" + dateTo + ")";

QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(queryString);

String codeUrlOrContent = "if (" + EnumElasticScriptField.URL_OR_CONTENT.getFieldName() + ".length() > 50) {" +
        "return " + EnumElasticScriptField.URL_OR_CONTENT.getFieldName() + ".substring(0, 50);" +
        "} else { " +
        "return " + EnumElasticScriptField.URL_OR_CONTENT.getFieldName() + "; }";

Script scriptUrlOrContent = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
        codeUrlOrContent, Collections.emptyMap());

Script scriptIsUrl = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
        EnumElasticScriptField.IS_URL.getFieldName(), Collections.emptyMap());

SearchResponse response = TRANSPORT_CLIENT.prepareSearch(MY_INDEX)
                .setTypes(MY_TYPE)
                .setSearchType(SEARCH_TYPE)
                .setQuery(query)
                .addScriptField(EnumLinkFields.URL_OR_CONTENT.getFieldName(), 
                     scriptUrlOrContent)
                .addScriptField(EnumLinkFields.IS_URL.getFieldName(), scriptIsUrl)
                .setFrom(offset)
                .setSize(count)
                .addSort(orderByField, sortOrder)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Note that the call to the setFetchSource function must be removed and all returned fields must be returned through the script.

Comment: Kudos. I don't work with java api so i can't say much about it. But let me know if my updated solution works. (for future reference).

Comment: @DEVCNN .You might need a return keyword in if block. I do not know much about elasticsearch and it's hard for me to test it. Let someone who is expert in this field comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script_fields query in the query object, i.e. in *setQuery(query)*.
Your query object should be looking like this right now.

```
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
```

After you add the script_fields in the object, it should become:

```
"query" : {
  "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
},
"script_fields": {
  "urlOrContent": {
     "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "if(params._source.urlOrContent.length() > 50){
                    params._source.urlOrContent.substring(0, 50)
                   }
                   else {
                   params._source.urlOrContent
                   }"  
   }
  }
}
```

The resulting hits will have a fields array with the substring you required.

**You have to enable scripting by changing the elasticsearch.yml file like so and restart the elasticsearch:**
**script.engine.painless.inline.aggs: on**

**script.engine.painless.inline.update: on**

**script.inline: on**

**script.indexed: on**

Comment: If the string length is less than 50 characters, an exception throws.